# Call class method into a return function callback not working in Typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm using a `node-schedule` for schedule a `synchronizeAll()` method. I'm trying this

```
constructor() {
    var schedule = require('node-schedule');

    var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();

    rule.minute = new schedule.Range(0, 59, 5);

    this.initializeDb().then(() => {
        schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function () {
            console.log('works!!');
            this.synchronizeAll();
        });
    });
}


synchronizeAll() {
    let synchronizeProjects: SynchronizeProjects;

    synchronizeProjects.synchronize().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

This project results in

```
works!!
/home/braulio/projetos/github/redtench/src/node/dist/redmine/redmine.js:14
                this.synchronizeAll();
                     ^

TypeError: this.synchronizeAll is not a function
```

I know the problem occurs because I am calling the class method within the calback function, however I do not know how to correct

Comment: try replace func(){} by () => {}. function keyword creates a new javascript's scope so this keyword is refering the callback function

Comment: Try schedule.scheduleJob(rule , () => { this.synchronizeAll(); }

I think you're losing your this reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @ConnorsFan figured this was probably a dup

Comment: @CaseyAnderson  - Yes. It is one of the two most popular questions on the Angular forum. :-)

Comment: Thanks guys... this solve my problem   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **this** keyword is losing the original reference inside of the callback function for scheduleJob. You can either store **this** in a variable (let t = this) prior to the this.initialiseDB() call, then do t.synchronizeAll(), or you can keep your **this** reference by using an arrow function like below.

```
schedule.scheduleJob(rule , () => { this.synchronizeAll(); }
```